# How to avoid a macro with optional argument to create any token?

Tags: conditionals, xparse, optional-arguments, token

I was trying to use a macro inside of `\cite` optional argument. I expected the optional argument to be ignored if the macro expands into nothing (i.e, get something like `[1]`), but sometimes a supposedly empty argument still gives something like `[1,]`.

```latex
%\usepackage{natbib,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\foo{m}{#1}
%\newcommand\foo[1]{#1}         % similar results
foo
\cite[\foo{}]{ref}              % [1]

\NewDocumentCommand\fooOpt{o m}{#2}
%\newcommand\fooOpt[2][dummy]{#2}  % similar results
fooOpt
\cite[\fooOpt{}]{ref}           % [1,]
\cite[\fooOpt[useless]{}]{ref}  % this one is broken, I suppose because of the nested []

\NewDocumentCommand\fooStar{s m}{\IfBooleanF{#1}{#2}}
fooStar
\cite[\fooStar{}]{ref}          % [1,]
\cite[\fooStar*{ignored}]{ref}  % [1,]
```

I found out that `natbib` uses the [`\if`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/if) command
to discriminate between empty and non-empty argument.
If you look at the sources of `natbib`, you will find `\if*#2*\else\NAT@cmt#2\fi` (which implies that the command will have unexpected behavior if the optional argument starts with `*`).
The problem seems to be that some of the macros I defined still created a token, despite the result being empty.

Based on that, I created this test case:

```latex
\def\YN[#1]{\if*#1*Y\else N\fi}
\YN[]           % Y
\YN[{}]         % Y
\YN[{{}}]       % N (weirdly, \cite[{{}}]{ref} produces [1], not [1,]
\YN[{{{}}}]     % N
\YN[\foo{}]     % Y
\YN[\fooOpt{}]  % N
\YN[\fooStar{}] % N
```

How can I change `\fooOpt` and `\fooStar` (and potentially any macro with a complex signature that contains at least one optional argument) such that this simple test returns `Y`?
I am particularly interested in the optional star argument (`\NewDocumentCommand{…}{s …}{…}`).
The def of `\YN` cannot be changed (because I can't edit the `natbib` package).

I am somewhat in the dark about how tokens work, and I don't understand the mechanisms behind this weird behavior.

Comment: Try using `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` instead of `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the parsing for an optional star or argument is not implemented expandably if you don't explicitly ask for it. In case of the first macro `\foo` the `m`-argument is actually grabbed expandably (even though the macro itself is defined `\protected`, but `\if` doesn't care for `\protected` and will expand them regardless -- however things that use `\futurelet` or any other assignment will not be expanded and result in some tokens that are not equal to `*` for `\if`).

You can change the implementation used to parse for optional arguments to a fully expandable one by using `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`, note however that the macro has to take one mandatory argument after all the optional stuff with this. Also parsing is a slight bit less stable with it (no way to distinguish `[` from `{[}` in expandable parsing, so `\fooOpt{[}` will break).

At least your test cases work out that way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\foo{m}{#1}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\fooOpt{o m}{#2}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\fooStar{s m}{\IfBooleanF{#1}{#2}}

% for things outside of this MWE I wouldn't suggest using `r` arguments,
% instead stick to `m` for required arguments
\NewDocumentCommand\YN{r[]}{\if*#1*Y\else N\fi\par}

\begin{document}
\YN[]           % Y
\YN[{}]         % Y
\YN[{{}}]       % N (weirdly, \cite[{{}}]{ref} produces [1], not [1,]
\YN[{{{}}}]     % N
\YN[\foo{}]     % Y
\YN[\fooOpt{}]  % Y and no longer N
\YN[\fooStar{}] % Y and no longer N
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked indeed! To bad that I was actually using commands with optional arguments at the end, but I guess this is the price to pay.